MSI not properly executed when called by Powershell
Cheers Smart-People of the Internet.
Rougth breakdown of what i'm trying to do:
Deploy different Windows version & Software via MDT.
One of the Softwares is a Monitoring-Software. The Provider of the Monitoring-Software offers me per location my customer has one MSI-file i can install to directly assign a maschine to it.
So i build two Powershell-Script. One Script which is only on a more secured Server, which gathers and drops all the installers into folder on a NAS. And one script which is ment for the operator (trainee) who is deploying the OS via MDT onto the maschine. The script gets called by MDTs TaskSequenz and the operator gets a prompt with a table conainting all the customers and they locations from which they can select what customers maschine is currently prept.
My current problem:
the script calles a MSI file from my NAS. Sometimes it executes corretly and installs the Monitoring-Software sometimes it doesnt. When it doesnt it just starts MSIEXEC, pops open the installation Windows and closes it after a second or so. No errors get displayed by MSIEXEC or returned to Powershell.
Here's the script-part where the Path gets assambled and executed with MSIEXEC.
$vtmp=($folders | Where-Object ListenID -EQ $inp1 | Select-Object Kunde,Standorte)

    if($vtmp.Standorte -gt 1){
        $trash=@()
        $i2=1
        foreach($location in $(Get-ChildItem "$($path)\$($vtmp.Kunde)"-Recurse -Directory)){

            $addtrash=@{
                ListenID=$i2++
                Standort="$($location.Name)"
            }

            $trash += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $addtrash
        }
        $trash | Format-Table
        $inp2=Read-Host "Select the desired Location"

        ## check if human input trash or usable information
        while ($trash.ListenID -notcontains $inp2){
            write-host -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Yellow "The entered ID is not conaited in the above list. Try again"
            if($inp2 -imatch '\d[a-zA-Z]*' -or '[a-zA-Z]')
                    {
                        Write-Host "You entered LETTERS."
                        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "DONT do that."
                        write-Host "Only numbers listed above are allowed"
                        Write-Host ""
                    }
            $inp2=Read-Host "Enter the ID of the desired Organisation"
        }
        ##
        
        $vtmp2=($trash | Where-Object ListenID -eq $inp2|Select-Object Standort)
        $msipath=((Get-ChildItem "$path\$($vtmp.kunde)\$($vtmp2.Standort)"-File "*.msi").FullName)
    }
    else{
        ((get-childitem "$path\$($vtmp.Kunde)\" -File "*.msi" -Recurse).FullName)       
    }
    start-process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i $msipath /passive /norestart -log C:\Windows\Temp\Monitoring.log" -wait

For everyone not speaking german a short translation:

Kunde = Customer
Standorte = locations

Here's the log of MSIEXEC when it "runs" the MSI called by the script.
(as screenshot since it's not readble otherwise or i suck at formating text)
MSIEXEC LOG
What i already tried:

Checked credentials to my NAS (Working, cause else i wouldnt even get the list of customers)
tried different credentials (build in ADMIN-User, same results)
added loging to MSIEXEC and checked to log: i cant find anything suspicios. (but dont understand the log completly aswell)
checked permissions on the executing user on the local Maschine (it's the build in Admin)
checked the MSI files: if executed by Hand (via Mouseclicks) all of them work just fine.
rebooted the Maschine: nothing changed
googled the symptoms: nothing...
Maybe Filepath/Names are to long? C:\test\Customer.MSI doesnt work either


this $msipath=((Get-ChildItem "$path\$($vtmp.kunde)\$($vtmp2.Standort)"-File "*.msi").FullName) could get you an array of file fullnames. Also, try with parameter -LiteralPath because the path you construct with "$path\$($vtmp.kunde)\$($vtmp2.Standort)" may contain characters like []. Did you check if the path to the wanted msi file actually exists?

The log reports error code -2147023570, which is https://www.hresult.info/FACILITY_WIN32/0x8007052E (ERROR_LOGON_FAILURE, "The user name or password is incorrect."). It also indicates an MSI exit code of 1620: "This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package."

Thanks to your comments Theo & mklement0 i found my error.
I forgot to set the $msipath in the ELSE condition of if($vtmp.Standorte -gt 1). i did assemble the path, but never put it in the $msipath variable. So the script tried to access a path that has not been set yet. Since there are far more customers with only one location, the script only rarely had to go the "more then one Location" path.
We tested it on a maschine (standalone as script) and within the MDT deployment multiple times.
Works just fine now. Somtimes "you can't see the forest for the trees
